# Multiply elements in dataframe column by same value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-breeze

With pandas/numpy, a 2x2 matrix multiplied with a 2x1 matrix will result in each column in 2x2 matrix by corresponding column value in 2x1 matrix.
Ex. The following with numpy

```
>>> data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> data
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> data * [2, 4]
array([[ 2,  8],
       [ 6, 16]])
```

How can this operation be done with spark/breeze? I tried unsuccessfully with `new DenseVector(2, 2, Array(1,2,3,4)) * DenseVector(2, 4)`.

Answer (score 3):

Spark `DataFrames` are not designed to linear algebra operations. Theoretically you can combine all columns using `VectorAssembler` and perform multiplications using `ElementwiseProduct`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ElementwiseProduct
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("x1", "x2"))
  .setOutputCol("xs")

val product = new ElementwiseProduct()
  .setScalingVec(Vectors.dense(Array(2.0, 4.0)))
  .setInputCol("xs")
  .setOutputCol("xs_transformed")

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0))).toDF("x1", "x2")

product.transform(assembler.transform(df)).select("xs_transformed").show
// +--------------+
// |xs_transformed|
// +--------------+
// |     [2.0,8.0]|
// |    [6.0,16.0]|
// +--------------+
```

but it is useful only for basic transformations.

Answer (score 1):

In Breeze, this is done with the special broadcasting value `*`.

```
scala> import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.linalg._

scala> val dm = DenseMatrix((1,2), (3,4))
dm: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Int] =
1  2
3  4

scala> dm(*, ::) :* DenseVector(2,4)
res0: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Int] =
2  8
6  16
```

dm(*, ::) says "apply the operation to every row". Scalar multiplication is `:*`, while matrix/shaped multiplication is `*`.

Comment: Great solution. It works with test case, though it doesn't seem safe when vector is longer than row. Here's numpy: `>>> data * [1,2,3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (3,)`.